# Control may reach end of non-void fct in recursive function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, return, function-definition

I know why and whats happening for this error. Mainly bc the return in inside the if. However Id like to fix the flow so its error/warning free.

Ive added inconsequential returns at the end as well as modifying the flow the best I could but with no luck.

```
int modifiedbinsearch_low(int* arr, int low, int high , int key){   
    if(low==high) return high ; 

    int mid = low + (high-low) /2;

    if(key >  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);  } 
    else  { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);  }  
}

int modifiedbinsearch_high(int* arr, int low, int high , int key){   
    if(low==high) return high ; 

    int mid = low + (high-low) /2;

    if(key <  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,low,mid,key);  } 
    else  { modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,mid+1,high,key);  } 

} 

int low = modifiedbinsearch_low( ...)
int high = modifiedbinsearch_high( ...)
```

Comment: Since you know already what is the problem what is your question?

Comment: @AnoopRana How can I fix the flow so I can make it error/warning free.

Comment: Ask yourself `"what do modifiedbinsearch_low and modifiedbinsearch_high return if low != high?"`.

Comment: `if(key >  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);  } 
    else  { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);  }` you do a recursive call but throw away the `int` value returned by the recursion and don't end up returning anything from modifiedbinsearch_low()

Comment: This is not really about being warning free. Your code is completely broken because you fail to return. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: The solution is really simple. Change `modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);` to `return modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);` and `modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);` to `return modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);` do the same for the _high funcion.

Comment: @drescherjm I didnt know the return could also be the function itself in recursion. Thanks a lot to you and everyone.

Comment: @Olivia22 *"How can I fix the flow so I can make it error/warning free."* -- isn't knowing the answer to this part of knowing "why and whats happening for this error"? It still looks to me like the question has no question.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about recursive functions is that they work exactly like non-recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both functions return nothing when the control is reached if statements

```
if(key >  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);  } 
else  { modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);  }
```

and

```
if(key <  arr[mid] ) { modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,low,mid,key);  } 
else  { modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,mid+1,high,key);  }
```

By the way the both functions have redundant parameters. For example it is enough to declare the function `modifiedbinsearch_low` the following way

```
int * modifiedbinsearch_low( int* arr, size_t n , int key);
```

That is similarly to the standard algorithm `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` the functions should return a pointer instead of a value of the type int.

If to call the function like for example

```
auto first = modifiedbinsearch_low( arr, n, key );
auto last = modifiedbinsearch_high( arr, n, key );
```

then the pair `first-last` shall determine the range `[first, last)` where elements with the value key are stored in the array.

I would declare and define the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 };

    auto first = modifiedbinsearch_low( a, std::size( a ), 2 );
    auto last = modifiedbinsearch_high( a, std::size( a ), 2 );

    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
2 2 2
```

If you want that the function would return indices instead of pointers then they can look the following way as it is shown in the next demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

size_t modifiedbinsearch_low( const int a[], size_t n, int key )
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else if (a[n / 2] < key)
    {
        return n / 2 + 1 + modifiedbinsearch_low( a + n / 2 + 1, n - n / 2 - 1, key );
    }
    else
    {
        return modifiedbinsearch_low( a, n / 2, key );
    }
}

size_t modifiedbinsearch_high( const int a[], size_t n, int key )
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else if (key < a[n / 2])
    {
        return modifiedbinsearch_high( a, n / 2, key );
    }
    else
    {
        return n / 2 + 1 + modifiedbinsearch_high( a + n / 2 + 1, n - n / 2 - 1, key );
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 };

    auto first = modifiedbinsearch_low( a, std::size( a ), 2 );
    auto last = modifiedbinsearch_high( a, std::size( a ), 2 );

    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        std::cout << a[first] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
2 2 2
```

If your compiler does not support the function `std::size` then this expression `std::size( a )` you may rewrite like `sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we encounter with these type of errors usually is because the function expects a return value but there is none. In my case there was no return if the first ***if logical block*** failed thus giving me the error.

***If you encounter this problem using recursion add return to the recursive function when it calls itself inside.***

Here is the solution given by @drescherjm in the comments;

```
int modifiedbinsearch_low(int* arr, int low, int high , int key){   
    if(low==high) return high ; 

    int mid = low + (high-low) /2;

    if(key >  arr[mid] ) { 
          return modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,mid + 1 , high,key);
    }   
    else  { 
          return modifiedbinsearch_low(arr,low,mid,key);  }  
    }

int modifiedbinsearch_high(int* arr, int low, int high , int key){   
    if(low==high) return high ; 

    int mid = low + (high-low) /2;

    if(key <  arr[mid] ) { 
          return modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,low,mid,key);  
    } 
    else  { 
          return modifiedbinsearch_high(arr,mid+1,high,key);  } 
    }
```